# In highcharts, is it possible to make a bar in a column chart with its top bordering the edge of the chart area "on top" of the chart border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4bk8fch/) for demonstration.

In the two bars shown in the above JSFiddle, the respective top and the bottom side of the two bars are not black, but grey, since that is the color of the chart border/border of plot area. Would it be possible to make the two bars to be "on top" of the chart border (so that all their sides are black)? I have tried with zIndex in "series". But that does not work.

These are the most relevant javascript code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        borderWidth: 1,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 100
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        animation: false  
      },
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2']
    },
    yAxis: {
           tickInterval: 10,
           min: -50,
           max: 50
    },

    series: [{
        data: [50,  -50],
        zIndex: 300
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this effect, you can set series.column.clip: false.
Disabling this option allows series rendering over plotArea borders.

```
series: [{
    clip: false,
    data: [50, -50]
  }]
```

Live demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2kyc4dbu/

API reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.clip